# Pull Google Wallet transactions and balance into Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, android-pay

For a personal project I want to pull all my transactions and daily balance into a spreadsheet. How do I go about achieving this? I'm new to app scripts/java but a nudge in the right direction would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Wallet transactions trigger an email confirmation. Could try just reading them with `GmailApp` after filtering them into 1 label. Parse the subject and body to get the transaction details. The Gmail example on the welcome screen (in the script editor >> Help >> Welcome) is a good start.

Comment: Ah! Didn't think of it like that, the email that comes through.  I can work with that, Thanks so much.